# Updating Maven version in Openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge, wildfly-10

I have an openshift gear running Wildfly 10. My web application requires Maven 3.3.X to build (it uses some plugins that requires it). How do I update my Openshift Gear to support that?